# Rails Active Record Sorting using Concat w/ nil values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Previously, to get a list of games to display, I've done:

```
@games = Game.all
```

I have 3 relevant columns that I want to use to sort with: `series`, `sort`, and `title`. I was trying to do a sort like this:

```
@games = Game.order (:series || :sort || :title)
```

But the resulting sort is all over the board, AND it drags all of the games with a `series` or `sort` to the top. I was hoping to CONCAT them all down into a single string, and use that resulting string as the sort, making it agnostic to whether `series` or `sort` might be `nil` (which over half of the results are).

Is this possible? Am I asking for too much here?

Comment: By concat, do you mean combining those three text fields into one field and ordering them alphabetically? i.e taking values  `exampleseries`, `examplesort`, `exampletitle` and making it `exampleseriesexamplesortexamplestitle` ?

Comment: @SyntacticFructose Exactly. Additionally, I don't want there to be spaces, because otherwise you could have a sort that begins `  exampletitle` and that's not desired. If there's no `series` or `sort`, it should just be `exampletitle` that is being sorted upon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to implement this:

```
Game.all.sort_by(&:sort_string)


###

class Game < ApplicationRecord
    def sort_string
        [series, sort, title].join('')
    end
end
```

`all` in this case would be replaced by your query, and after the query you'll sort by a custom method on your model

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. Still kinda new to Rails syntax, so trying to figure all that out.